# AWS update war file on ec2 tomcat in auto scaling group behind loadbalancer

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have a VPC which contains a load-balancer in public subnet
and have 3 Web server ec instances (tomcat7) in private subnet, Instances are launched through auto scaling group. Initially 2 instances were launched (min instance setting was 2). I then manually(SSH) installed java and tomcat and copied war file.

every thing is working fine

**I have few confusions**

1 - How newly created instance will have java + tomcat + war installed, Only place i can suspect is "Launch Configuration" -> Advanced Details -> User data
I am planning to write follow text in that filed

```
sudo su root
apt-get update
apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
apt-get install -y tomcat7
some command to get war file from some where (S3)
```

2 - **Live upgrade**: Let say autoscalling and load has reached to 7 instances, and if I want to update war with new version file, how will that happen, is it has to go through manual SSH and update or is there any automatic way to update and sync every thing on all scaled instances (while user are still accessing website)?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the war on s3, and this makes sense for [cloudinit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) (though it runs as root, so no need for sudo). This is how autoscaling machines come up too.

For upgrading the war, you need to push the war file out in some manner and restart tomcat*- this is why people use Chef/Puppet/Ansible/Salt.

If this is overwhelming, you should use [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html). It'll definitely simplify things.

`*` you don't actually have to restart tomcat, but you don't want to go down the PermGen rabbithole.